# What compound should I use to fill drilled holes in cinder block?

Tags: repair, brick, concrete-block

I have some holes drilled previously on my house that I would like to fill in. Do they make a liquid concrete in a tube compound that I can squeeze into the holes to fill them in and keep wasps out? Outer part of brick has stucco as well.

Comment: Are they weep holes?  If so, you don't want to fill them in.

Comment: @Joe: No  because I drilled them myself :)

Comment: Well, I'd say you're the authority on that, then. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quikrete](http://www.kk.org/cooltools/archives/004031.php) mortar repair sounds like it would do the trick.

Comment: that looks like it will do it! Thanks never knew it existed :)

Comment: I've not used it personally so let me know how it works!

Comment: @yhw42: Went to Lowe's and got the $1.99 tube. Works great. Used an old wet sponge to wipe away the excess. Takes 24 hrs to dry but results look promising. Should be ready for paint by tomorrow.