# What should I use to fill drilled concrete holes that are not used anymore?

Tags: concrete, sealing

Just wanted to do some home repairs and found lots of old drilled holes.

I've used putty to cover them up but it occurred to me that there would be air gaps for the holes as the putty cover over them only.

I went searching around online and there has been no definite answer.

I've saw [selleys no more gap](http://www.selleys.com.au/fillers/flexible-gap-filler/multi-purpose) and was wondering if it was a good choice to push this sealant into the concrete or perhaps those adhesives sold in a caulking gun would be a good choice.

I am afraid that next time i'll re-drill the holes at the same place and it would crumble.

I've saw [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/what-compound-should-i-use-to-fill-drilled-holes-in-cinder-block) but from where I am, they do not sell them.

Comment: We have a few small holes left from insect treatments, we had to have a structural engineer approve the house for insurance because of other things around the house and asked him about them. We followed his advice and filled them with concrete colored 100% silicone "caulk"

Comment: I suppose it depends on what the concrete is used for (exterior, interior, walls, slab, wall, column, etc.). What about epoxy?

Comment: @Nick the concrete is an interior wall.

Comment: I have used this in the past. It works to fill holes previously drilled: http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3037768&KPID=4550764&kpid=4550764&pla=pla_4550764

Comment: possible duplicate of [What compound should I use to fill drilled holes in cinder block?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/what-compound-should-i-use-to-fill-drilled-holes-in-cinder-block)

Comment: Maybe trying patching holes in concrete with concrete? Call me crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hydraulic cement would be a reasonable choice for patching small holes in concrete - since that's what it's made for. Be sure to wet the hole first, then pack in the cement and level it off.

Comment: hmm.. then how do we ensure that there are no air gaps? I'll accept your answer in 2 days time.

Comment: You can use various techniques to improve the packing - something like a nail about half the diameter of the hole, with the point ground off flat can be used to pack the cement in the the hole - it can't be too close to the size of the hole, or it becomes a piston. A very small tube or straw could also be placed into the hole to allow air to leave as the cement in pushed in, and withrawn after cement reaches the back, but I think you'll find that lovely in theory, but far too much bother to actually do in real life.

Comment: And the air-gap issue -- and the possible solutions to it -- are the same fot any patch material.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do please do not use anything out of a caulking gun, caulk in any form is not suitable for cement of concrete block repairs. I have just spent many hours digging that stuff out of the block and the concrete floor that the former owner thought was an appropriate fix of didn't bother to repair.
Please don't take this as a product spam, it's just the product I found at my locally owned hardware store.
The product I used was DAP cement patch. I'll warn you for the bigger holes it took up to 3 applications to achieve a nice flush patch. The bonus is the product is as solid as the cement surrounding it, so durability shouldn't be a problem. As the floor and block had been previously painted, I did prime the porous patches before the final coat of paint.
It did turn out darn nice. It wasn't the least labor intensive way, for sure, but the end result was worth the investment.